# Cannot install pip for python3 on mac

Tags: macos, pip

When I run

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

It gives me this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /var/root/.pip/pip.log
```

However if I just run:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

There is no problem:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=445a893564065937c0f31ac2cc8e2f35
  Downloading pip-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.1
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple permissions issue. If you're installing to the system Python installation, you should need root, which is what `sudo` provides.

If you need to install stuff where you don't have root privileges, you need to look into Python [virtual environments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).